# I want to have a next and previous link that featches the next and previous article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pagination, will-paginate

In a simple blog application where someone can read an article and decide to read the next article without going through the list of articles again but click the next button and it takes the person to the next article on this list. How can this be done. I have worked with willpaginate and kaminari and they are both great plugins for pagination.

So now in the show action i want to have a next and previous link that featches the next and previous article how do i do this

simple code sample below to work with

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to `Article` to get the next and previous articles depending on what you mean by next and previous - i.e. what order you want the articles in.

E.g. with `created_at` used to define the order

```
def next
  self.class.find(
    :first, 
    :conditions => ["created_at > ?", self.created_at], 
    :order => 'created_at, id')
end

def previous
  self.class.find(
    :first, 
    :conditions => ["created_at < ?, self.created_at],
    :order => 'created_at desc, id desc')
```

That assumes that nothing has the same created at date which might be a bit too simplistic so you might want to check against the id too. Something like:

```
    :conditions => ["created_at > ? or (created_at = ? and id > ?)", self.created_at, self.created_at, self.id]
```

If you just want to order by id then it is even more trivial as the ids can never be the same:

```
def next
  self.class.find(:first,
    :conditions => ['id > ?', self.id],
    :order => 'id')
end

def previous
  self.class.find(:first,
    :conditions => ['id < ?', self.id],
    :order => 'id desc')
end
```

Comment: i dont want to paginate a list of array i just want to go to an artiscl and read and instead of going to the index action to view more i want to read the next article by clicking the next button so it gets the article with the id higher than the one i am reading

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. So on your show page you can do `link_to("Next", article_url(@article.next))`. If it's just by id that you want then your condition is even easier, you can just check that the id is greater than the one you have and order by id.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of using just the id to retrieve next and previous articles.

Comment: i implemented your solution here http://test.tektweet.com/stories/464-next-generation-portable-ps-vita-review at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Willpaginate plugin which solves Your problem.
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: i dont want to paginate a list of array i just want to go to an artiscl and read and instead of going to the index action to view more i want to read the next article by clicking the next button so it gets the article with the id higher than the one i am reading.

Comment: The OP mentions the will_paginate gem in the question.